# Domino Index not updating correctly

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus-notes

I got a strange issue regarding Domino fulltext-indexing:
When I save a document, and update the index (updall or via database properties) the index seems to still contain the old values.
So, if I update the field, lets say, 'Assignee' from value 'x' to value'y' and then update the index I can still find the document via FTSearch "[Assignee] = x", but not with "[Assignee] = y".
But the document has already the value "y" in it.
The index is only correct again, when I recreate it completely.

I'm using Domino 9.0.1

Is that some permission problem, or why would this happen?

Comment: It takes up to 15 minutes to refresh full text index - have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27269411/2065611

Comment: Check on database properties the number of unindexed documents

Comment: It also happens when I update the index manually. Count unindexed documents says "All are indexed"

Comment: Does the search work now after an hour passed?

Comment: It doesn't. I forgot to mention, that there are documents that are there for several days, with the same problem. The index seems only to be correct when I completely rebuild it.

Comment: how do you update the FT index exactly? properties box or code?

Comment: The frequency setting is "immediate". I tried it with updall and with property box "Update Index". I also added database.updateFTIndex to the code, that saves the document. That doesn't work either.

Comment: Does the search work in Notes client's full text search bar?

Comment: Is Update task running on server? Does full text search refresh work for other databases on same server?

Comment: How about in a local replica with an existing full text index? Does that also fail?